# Get a poster from a video with (html5 canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to extract my poster image from the video file .I tried the html5 and canvas (https://github.com/codepo8/videograbber) but when i click on the image to store it below, nothing is shown and i checked the code i found that there is no "src" generated!
See here how it should be like: http://isithackday.com/videograbber/

My objective is to save the image into my project folder!
The code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Taking screengrabs from video in Canvas</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<style>
  *{margin:0;padding:0;font-size:15px;font-family:calibri,arial,sans-serif}
  footer,section,header{display:block;}
  body{padding:2em;background:#666;color:#fff;}
  h1{font-size:24px;margin:10px 0;}
  h2{font-size:18px;margin:10px 0;color:lime;}
  canvas{display:block;border:2px solid #000;}
  #video,#canvas{float:left;padding-right:10px;}
  #video{width:640px;}
  #save li{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}
  #save{clear:both;padding:10px 0;overflow:auto;}
  #save img{float:left;padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:5px;}
  footer a{color:lime;}
  footer p{margin:5em 0 1em 0;padding:1em 0;border-top:1px solid #999}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <header><h1>Taking screengrabs from video in Canvas (Chrome, Mozilla, Opera, Safari - maybe IE (got no windows))</h1></header>
  <section>
    <p>Simply play the video. Every time you pause, you can see the screenshot on the right. Click the screenshot to store it in your collection below.</p>
<div id="video">
  <h2>The Video:</h2>
  <video controls>
    <source src="meetthecubs.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    <source src="meetthecubs.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
  </video>
</div>
<div id="canvas">
  <h2>Preview (click to store images below):</h2>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
<div id="save">
  <h2>Your saved images:</h2>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
</section>
<footer>
  <p>Written by 
    <a href="http://wait-till-i.com/">Chris Heilmann</a> - 
    <a href="http://twitter.com/codepo8">@codepo8</a>
  </p>
</footer>
<script>

(function(){

  var v = document.querySelector('video'),
      n = document.querySelector('source').src.replace(/.*\/|\..*$/g,''),
      c = document.querySelector('canvas'),
      save = document.querySelector('#save ul'),
      ctx = c.getContext('2d');

  v.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function(ev){

    var ratio = v.videoWidth/v.videoHeight,
        w = 400,
        h = parseInt(w / ratio, 10),
        time = 0,
        img = null,
        li = null;

    c.width = w;
    c.height = h + 40;

    v.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(ev){
      if(v.paused){
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.drawImage(v, 0, 40, w, h);
        ctx.font = '20px Calibri';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'lime';
        ctx.fillText(n, 5, 20);
        time = format(v.currentTime);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fillText(time, 395 - ctx.measureText(time).width, 20);
      }
    },false);

    c.addEventListener('click',function(ev){
      li = document.createElement('li');
      img = document.createElement('img');
      li.appendChild(img);
      save.appendChild(li);
      img.src = ctx.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    },false);

  },false);

  function format(time){
    var hours = parseInt((time / 60 / 60) % 60, 10),
        mins = parseInt((time / 60) % 60, 10),
        secs = parseInt(time, 10) % 60,
        hourss = (hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + parseInt(hours, 10) + ':',
        minss = (mins < 10 ? '0' : '') + parseInt(mins, 10) + ':',
        secss  = (secs < 10 ? '0' : '') +(secs % 60),
        timestring = ( hourss !== '00:' ? hourss : '' ) + minss + secss;
    return timestring;
  };
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the problem is with the event "click" not "timeupdate". If you check the code source you will find just <img> without "src" the problem is in this line of code"img.src = ctx.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');"  is not executed. I don't know why!!

Comment: Hum missed the thing sorry. And you're not getting any errors in the console? Like a 'Security Exception' ? If your video comes from a different domain, it has to be served with proper cross-origin headers from the server and you have to set the video's `crossOrigin` attribute before setting the sources. Otherwise, your canvas will be tainted and you won't be able to call `toDataURL`. (Tested your code with a local video (localhost, not `file://`) and it works well. Note that `file://` protocol is considered as cross-origin too and will also taint your canvas.

Comment: i already try it with local video (that it is in a folder in my project) but it does not work :/

Comment: When you say local video, is it still on a server? Don't you have an error in the console?

Comment: local= just in a folder of my project, and there is no errors shown in the console

Comment: yes but your project is served by a server or not?

Comment: yes, anyway  my problem is solved with FireFox 22, before i used chrome